# Need to pass different default values to different child component form from parent and doesn't want to loose either default value on rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to set pass 2 different default values to 2 different child component from parent. But i am not able.Some how whether it is first defaultvalue or second defaultvalue get rendered to 2 different child components.
Here is my code below

```
function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
      defaultValues: {},
      defaultValuesSecond: {},
      callSecond: false
    })

function updateDefaultValues(data,showForm,showContactD, callSecond ) {
    if(!callSecond){
    setState({
      ...state,
      defaultValues: data,
      showForm:showForm
    })
  }
  else{
    setState({
      ...state,
      defaultValuesSecond: data,
      callSecond:callSecond
    })
  }
  }
<div>
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ isView: false }}>
          
          <Child1
            defaultValues={defaultValues}
            updateDefaultValues={updateDefaultValues}
            callSecond={callSecond}
            defaultValuesSecond={defaultValuesSecond}
          />
        </AppContext.Provider>
      </div>
    )
```

```
function Child1({  defaultValues, updateDefaultValues, showForm, callSecond, defaultValuesSecond }) {
  
  const methods = useForm({ defaultValues, mode: 'onChange' })
return(
{<Child2 methods={methods}
        updateDefaultValues={updateDefaultValues}  />}
     
      { <Child3 defaultValues={defaultValues}/>}  
      
      {<Child4  updateDefaultValues={updateDefaultValues}
      
      callSecond={callSecond} 
       defaultValues={defaultValuesSecond}/>} 
)}


function Child2(){
fun1(){
updateDefaultValues()
}
return(
//call fun1
)}

function Child3(){
 { setValue, getValues, watch, reset, setError, clearErrors } = useForm(defaultValues),
}
return(
render default values in someform fields
)}

function Child4(){


return(
<Child 6>
<Child7>
}

functional Child6(){
fun1(){
updateDefaultValues()
}
}

Function Child7(){
const {  getValues, setValue, clearErrors } = useForm({ defaultValues, mode: 'onChange' })
return(
// render defaultValues on some form fields
)
}
```

My idea is to pass different defaultvalues to child3 and child7 based on different API call, and both different defaultvalues variable are maintained at parent and passed it along.
I am able to get different values of 2nd defaultvalues at Child7 from 2nd api call but on rendering it prints values of 1st defaultvalue from 1st api call.

Could you please assist me on this.
I have tried to take 2nd defaultvalue on some variable then render it but it doesnt. Always render 1st defaultvalues from 1st api.

Comment: Guys, i was able to solve this problem with the help of reset and setValue api of useform. You have to use this in your useffect and reset default values in parent or child where ever you want. Problem i faced was due to use of custom ControllerField which itself had some useEffect logic.